# Can't get into Google Play Store after changing Gmail password

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-services, google-account

After resetting my Gmail password, my Android phone (Galaxy S4) can't get into the Google Play Store. It keeps telling me "*A change in your account requires that you sign in again.*"

I sign in with correct password (if it's the wrong password, I get an error). It then brings me to a screen where I can choose either my Gmail account or add a new account. I select the Gmail account, but it brings me right back to the screen that tells me a change in my account requires that I sign in again. Over and over!

This had been accompanied by a Google Play Services notification they would not go away telling me to update my password. I disabled notifications for that.

Comment: I think you'll have to wait for 72 hours or something. Let me check it again. Edit: Okay, I read the **Important:** note [here](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6172890?hl=en). Not sure though, whether it applies on this question as well.

Comment: Doesn't seem to quite apply to my scenario, but I wonder if there may be something to waiting for 72 hours.  Maybe I'll just wait and see.  Thanks!

Comment: I encountered the same problem just a few minutes ago. It could also be a Google service disruption, since I have never experienced anything before. Or just a bad coincidence, that you face the same problem at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Just waiting may fix it if there is some sort of slow sync between Google services. A simple reboot might fix it. I would try deleting your cache and data for the play store app as well. If that doesn't work try deleting and re-adding your Google account under settings > Accounts > Google.

Answer (score 0):

- Clear data of your Play Store App and Gmail App.
- Reboot your Device.

Comment: Android 6.0 and newer do not show the `Clear Data` button in most phones. So your answer is valid only if the Android version is lower than said

Comment: Every Android Phone has options to do a `Clear Data` .

Comment: Grow up, no one knows everything